# Is it possible to setup mswjs in Nuxt 3 for both client and server side

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, msw

I'm trying to setup msw on my Nuxt 3 project. It's easy to setup for the browser but I'm stuck on setup for the server side. Does anyone have experience of this. Thank you!